# How to get the data from logfile if the input and logdata are in different format?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

My log file data is

```
[10/04/16 02:07:20 BST] Data 1
[11/04/16 02:07:20 BST] Data 1
[10/05/16 04:11:09 BST] Data 2
[12/05/16 04:11:09 BST] Data 2
[11/06/16 06:22:35 BST] Data 3
```

My input format is

```
./filename Apr 11 16 00:00:00 Jul 10 16 00:00:00
```

I am converting the input format to logfile format with the following function,

```
convert_date () {
local months=( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )
local i

for (( i=0; i<11; i++ )); do
    [[ $1 = ${months[$i]} ]] && break
done
printf "\[%2d\/%02d\/%02d $4 BST\]\n" $2 $(( i+1 )) $3 

for (( i=0; i<11; i++ )); do
    [[ $5 = ${months[$i]} ]] && break
done    
}
```

And also I am storing the result in variable and using it

```
Start=$( convert_date $1 $2 $3 $4 )
End=$( convert_date $5 $6 $7 $8 )
```

But the codes gives me result only if the Stattime and endtime are present in the log file. How can I get the data between the two times even if the start and endtimes are not present in the logfile. What awk script can I use?

Comment: Please can you add a sample/example i/p and o/p

Comment: My input will be `./filename Apr 10 16 00:00:00 Jun 11 16 00:00:00` and my output should be from Data1 to Data 3

Answer (score 0):

Your Bash (assumed) function seems to output date in following format:

```
$ bash test.sh "Apr 11 16 00:00:00"
\[11\/04\/16 00:00:00 BST\]
```

Working with that, test.awk:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[[/: ]+"; # set field separator to all delimiters in datetime format in the date                                                    
    split(start,arr,"[\\\\[/ :]") # split the start variable in pieces for reorganize 
    start=arr[4]" "arr[3]" "arr[2]" "arr[5]" "arr[6]" "arr[7] # reorganize
}
start <= $4" "$3" "$2" "$5" "$6" "$7 # compare reorganized data to date in start variable

$ awk -v start="\[11\/04\/16 00:00:00 BST\]" -f test.awk test.in 
[11/04/16 02:07:20 BST] Data 1
[10/05/16 04:11:09 BST] Data 2
[12/05/16 04:11:09 BST] Data 2
[11/06/16 06:22:35 BST] Data 3
```

It complains a bit, though:
    `awk: warning: escape sequence '\[' treated as plain '['`

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The input format is in "Input.Format" file and the log file is in "Log.File". This shell script 'cat' both files and pipes to 'awk'. The awk script changes the month format to number an compares to log file to turn on or off a print switch.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat Input.Format Log.File | awk 'BEGIN {
    Month = "  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
    } {
    if (NR == 1) {
       startm = index(Month, $2) / 3
       if (length(startm) == 1) { startm = "0" startm }
       startm = $4 startm $3
       endm = index(Month, $6) / 3
       if (length(endm) == 1) { endm = "0" endm }
       endm = $4 endm $3
#      print startm "  " endm
       }
    else {
       logdate = substr($1,8,2) substr($1,5,2) substr($1,2,2)
#      print logdate
       if (logdate >= startm ) { prtsw = 1 }
       if (logdate > endm ) { prtsw = 0 }
       if (prtsw == 1 ) { print $0 }
       }
    }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer